# How to apply tinny and quiet sound fix on new Lenovo 7i running Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: sound, kernel, alsa, lenovo, 22.04

I'm attempting to apply a fix I found for an issue. I recently purchased a 2022 Lenovo Yoga 7 (16IAP7). I'm running Ubuntu 22.04 on it, and the speaker sound is audible but it's very quiet and tinny. Only 2 of 4 speakers are actually playing. This seems to be a common problem and I found [this thread](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=208555#c645) which has several workarounds and solutions.

How do I apply this "[single modprobe](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=208555#c683)" fix to my machine: `options snd-sof-intel-hda-common hda_model=alc287-yoga9-bass-spk-pin`?

I tried adding the line to the end of **/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf** and rebooting but that didn't help. I also tried changing `yoga9` to `yoga7` to fit my model but that was unsuccessful. I'm not sure whether I'm applying the fix incorrectly or whether it's not working. Other users have a **/etc/modprobe.d/snd.conf** file, but that's missing on my computer. Another user (cris223) with the same model machine claims the fix works, which makes me think I'm just making an error due to my unfamiliarity with modprobe and the kernel.

Comment: OP, did you find any solution?  I am also facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same laptop & problem on Kubuntu 22.04; discovered the solution from the [Linux Mint forums](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?p=2286917#p2286917).

This is a kernel issue (this laptop has a separate treble & bass circuit apparently) and a patch was added in the 5.18 kernel (Ubuntu 22.04 uses 5.15).

You can [safely upgrade the kernel](https://easylinuxtipsproject.blogspot.com/p/hacks-mint.html#ID8.1) by installing the latest OEM kernel from Ubuntu (official stable kernel for newer hardware):

```sh
sudo apt-get install linux-oem-22.04c
```

Reboot your laptop; your speakers should now be working properly and your kernel updated.

```sh
$ uname -r
6.1.0-1004-oem
```